# Bottom pixel overflow in stepper view widget inside scaffold

Tags: dart, flutter

I have flutter app that contain `Stepper` Widget. My stepper is wrapped with `Scaffold`. And in my stepper contains `Column` with two `TextFormField`.

Whenever i touch input Text field in my `TextFormField`, then Keyboard show up with warning/error bottom pixel overflowed by 11 pixels.

I already tried add `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false` on Scaffold in page `root.dart`. It does remove bottom pixel overflowed by 11 pixels warning/error. But my 'BottomAppNavigation' is dissapear, like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLI8w.png

Also already add `singleChildScrollView`on Scaffold in page `root.dart` and it gives error:

```
I/flutter (21466): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
I/flutter (21466):   RenderStack#d0145 relayoutBoundary=up16 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
```

Root.dart

```
return Scaffold(
        body: PageView(
          children: [
            HomePage(
                userId: _userId,
                auth: widget.auth,
                onSignedOut: _onSignedOut),
            MyStepper(),
            Account("Account screen"),
          ],
          onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
          controller: _pageController,
 ),
```

MyStepper() is calling different dart file. This is MyStepper() page code:

MyStepper.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.lightGreen,
  ),
  title: 'App',
  home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Add Device')),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          _myStepper(),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: _buttonBottomBar(),
          )
        ],
      )),
);
}

Widget _myStepper() {
return Stepper(
  type: StepperType.horizontal,
  currentStep: _currentStep,
  onStepTapped: (int step) => setState(() => _currentStep = step),
  controlsBuilder: _createEventControlBuilder,
  onStepContinue:
      _currentStep < 2 ? () => setState(() => _currentStep += 1) : null,
  onStepCancel:
      _currentStep > 0 ? () => setState(() => _currentStep -= 1) : null,
  steps: <Step>[
    Step(
      title: Text('Connect'),
      content:
          _stepOne(),
      isActive: _currentStep >= 0,
      state: _currentStep >= 0 ? StepState.complete : StepState.disabled,
    ),
  ],
);
}

Widget _stepOne() {
return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          onSaved: (String value) {
            data.ssid = value;
          },
          maxLines: 1,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 1) {
              return 'SSID!';
            }
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'enter SSID',
              hintText: 'enter SSID',
              icon: const Icon(Icons.wifi),
              labelStyle:
              TextStyle(decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.solid)),
        ),
        TextFormField(
          onSaved: (String value) {
            data.password = value;
          },
          maxLines: 1,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 1) {
              return 'password SSID!';
            }
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'pass SSID',
              hintText: 'pass SSID',
              icon: const Icon(Icons.signal_wifi_4_bar_lock),
              labelStyle:
              TextStyle(decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.solid)),
        ),
      ],
);
}
```

Comment: Add property to scaffold avaoidToreszieBottomPadding false or try listview or SingleChildScrollView as a widget

Comment: @user3391680 - Why are you Using `MaterialApp` & `Scaffold` again in MyStepper.dart when they are already present at root.dart - This is not at all recommended.

Comment: @Nudge already done it, see my description.

Comment: @anmol.majhail well, if i not use scaffold again it works, but i lost my Appbar